# How do I return all results associated with an input cell in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

I have a time study data set that has three different order types and resulting times to fulfill that order. An Order Type will be entered into `C8`. In cells `C9:C`, I want to create an auto-updating list of Fulfillment Times that are correlated to the Order Type in `C8`.

For example, `C8` can say "Custom" and `C9:C` will vertically list Fulfillment Times 0:12:00, 0:13:00, 0:14:00. If I change C8 to "Kit", `C9:C` will list 0:07:00.

I know there's a simple solution, but I'm having a hard time figuring it out.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Try the built-in function FILTER. If you need further help add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query formula

```
=QUERY(A2:B6,"select B where A= ' "&C1&" ' ")
```

#### Pro tip:

To take it further.
Notice the little triangle on the right side of cell `C1`? We can apply `Data Validation` in the word search cell with `List of items` using `Custom,Kit,Basic`

*(Please do adjust ranges to your needs)*

[image]

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)

Comment: Welcome. 
Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.